# SQL: Number of different characters within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table:

```
A     B    
abcde abcdf 
bcdef bcdef
cdefg fgecd
```

I want the following:

```
A     B     Number_of_different_characters
abcde abcdf 1
bcdef bcdef 0
cdefg fgecd 4
```

where the third column counts the number of different characters. Please note that these strings need to be in the same order.

Thanks!

## Edited

I basically want the number of different characters in a string (where order matters) between column A and B. So column C would only display 0 if A = B. The length of the strings in A and B can be assumed to be equal.

Comment: Use `soundex()` or some other method.  What if there are duplicates?  How different is "abcabc" and "aabbcc"?

Comment: what have you tried so far and what are your results, also can you create a SQL Fiddle so that we have something to work with

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

the "brute force" answer, you need as many sum as max length of string
i suppose there is better answer for this.
**Instead of unions (RES) after FROM put simply your table**

```
    SELECT
        RES.*, 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 1, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 1, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 2, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 2, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 3, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 3, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 4, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 4, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 5, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 5, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 6, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 6, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 7, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 7, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 8, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 8, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(RES.A, 9, 1)=SUBSTRING(RES.B, 9, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        AS [Number_of_different_characters]
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT 'abcde' AS A, 'abcdf' AS B 
        UNION
        SELECT 'bcdef' AS A, 'bcdef' AS B 
        UNION
        SELECT 'cdefg' AS A, 'fgecd' AS B 
    ) AS RES
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a scalar function and take arguments from column A and column B to determine the string difference.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_DETECT_STR_DIFF(@STRINGA VARCHAR(10), @STRINGB VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @X INT,@LOOPCNT INT,@DIFFCNT INT = 0
SET @LOOPCNT = 1
SET @X = (SELECT TOP 1 LEN(A) FROM [table])
WHILE (@LOOPCNT <= @X)
BEGIN
DECLARE @COMPA VARCHAR(1), @COMPB VARCHAR(2)
SET @COMPA = (SUBSTRING(@STRINGA,@LOOPCNT,1))
SET @COMPB = (SUBSTRING(@STRINGB,@LOOPCNT,1))

IF @COMPA != @COMPB
BEGIN
SET @DIFFCNT = @DIFFCNT + 1
END
SET @LOOPCNT = @LOOPCNT + 1
END

RETURN @DIFFCNT
END

SELECT *,DBO.FN_DETECT_STR_DIFF(A,B) AS DIFFERENCE FROM [table]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive CTE to step through the characters of the strings one by one and compare if they are equal. If not add 1 to a counter. Mark the records where the last character was compared and use that marker to select the end result.

```
WITH cte(n, d, a, b, e)
AS
(
SELECT 0 n,
       0 d,
       a,
       b,
       0 e
       FROM elbat
       WHERE len(a) = len(b)
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1 n,
       d + CASE 
             WHEN substring(a, n + 1, 1) <> substring(b, n + 1, 1)
               THEN 1
             ELSE
               0
           END d,
       a,
       b,
       CASE
         WHEN len(a) = n
           THEN 1
         ELSE
           0
       END e
       FROM cte
       WHERE n <= len(a)
)
SELECT a,
       b,
       d
       FROM cte
       WHERE e = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af208/4)